# eclipse c++ Mac gdb debugger

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, debugging, gdb

macOS Mojave version 10.14, 64-bit
Eclipse version 4.10.0 for C++
GDB version 8.2.1

```
> Installed GDB with Homebrew.
> created gdb-cert with self signed root, type code signing, override defaults, always trust code signing.
> signed cert with: $ codesign -fs gdb-cert gdbPath
> created .gdbinit file with: $ echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
> eclipse > run > debug configurations > debugger > GDB Debugger > gdbPath
> eclipse > run > debug configurations > debugger > GDB Command File > .gbdinit path
```

I can build and run my C++ program from eclipse fine.
However, when debugging I get the problem below, (please check gdb is code signed - see tasked(8)). I checked the other thread that ran into the same error, and it appears I did everything how I was supposed to.

[image]

P.S. I have been coding in both Mac and Windows side by side for the past 3 years and my experience time and again has been that setting up any environment for Windows takes only a couple steps and is much simpler than setting one up for Mac. Why do people prefer Mac for developing?